# IOS how to loop correctly while performing checks

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, if-statement, count

I Need to loop a Dictionary array which contains two keys, one object and one date. I want to loop all the way to do a check at the same time. When objects are found the same there will be an increment of count.

Once i log it out the codes it shows this:

```
value of severity (
        {
        Severity = Warning;
        createdDate = "2015-12-09";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 2;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Warning;
        createdDate = "2015-12-08";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    },
        {
        Severity = Informational;
        createdDate = "2015-12-05";
        noOfOccurence = 1;
    }
)
```

As you can see during `2015-12-08` there are 2 noOfOccurence at index 1. But at index 2 there are also another `2015-12-08` that has 1 noOfOccurence. It is wrong as this date at index 1 and 2 are the same the total noOfOccurence for `2015-12-08` should be 3.

Here is the code that i use:

```
dictionForSeverity = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //code for same severity type for the same date
    for (int i = 0; i < feeds.count; i++)
    {
        int count =1;
        BOOL flag = false;
        for (int j = i+1; j< feeds.count; j++)
        {
            if ([[feeds objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToDictionary:[feeds objectAtIndex:j]])
            {
                count++;
                flag = true;
                [feeds removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }


        if (flag == true)
        {
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] forKey:@"Severity"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForSeverity copy]];
        }
        else
        {
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] forKey:@"Severity"];
            [dictionForSeverity setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForSeverity copy]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"value of severity %@",arrFinalValues);

    //giving values according to date manage/replace object of an array according to date
    for (int i=0; i<arrFinalValues.count; i++)
    {
        long indexOfObject;
        NSLog(@"%@",[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] );
        if ( [[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Informational"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrInformation replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Warning"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrWarning replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrCritical replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
        else if ([[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Emergency"])
        {
            indexOfObject = [dateArrForXais indexOfObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            [arrEmergency replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfObject withObject:[[arrFinalValues objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"noOfOccurence"]];
        }
    }
```

Qns: i want to count the number of identical objects that occurs the same date correctly. Please assist me! Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all this, use a dictionary that has four items, all [NSCountedSets](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/):

- A countedSet for "Warning".
- A countedSet for "Informational".
- A countedSet for "Emergency".
- A countedSet for "Critical".

Each of these countedSets will contain dates, and a count for that date.  That count will be maintained for you automatically as you add a set member or take one out.

All you do to create it is to go through your feed, and you grab the severity, and get the countedSet from the dictionary and then add the date to the dictionary, and go to the next feed entry, until you are done.

It will look like this:

```
Dictionary:
    key: "Warning"        object: countedSet of dates
    key: "Informational"  object: countedSet of dates
    key: "Emergency"      object: countedSet of dates
    key: "Critical"       object: countedSet of dates
```

This should allow you to quickly look for each severity level and see the dates you had those errors, and how many repeats on each date.

Alternatively, you could use the date as keys and the severity as the set items, and that would let you look for a date and see how many of each severity messages you had on that date.  That would look like this:

```
Dictionary:
    key: 2015-12-05      object: countedSet of severity
    key: 2015-12-07      object: countedSet of severity
    key: 2015-12-08      object: countedSet of severity
    key: 2015-12-08      object: countedSet of severity
```

Each set will only contain 4 items (Warning, Informational, Emergency, Critical) and the set would maintain counts for each.

Comment: it have been solved. it happened that i use a if statement. Once i change to While loop it works

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < feeds.count; i++)
    {
        int count =1;
        BOOL flag = false;
        for (int j = i+1; j< feeds.count; j++)
        {
            //if same type of dictionary found multiple times then manage it's count and remove the same one as well
            while ([[feeds objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToDictionary:[feeds objectAtIndex:j]])
            {
                count++;
                flag = true;
                //removing the same entry
                [feeds removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionForClassification = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        //if flag is true mean same type of severity is present multiple time in same date then manage final array (to show on arrFinalValues) for graph
        if (flag == true)
        {
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Classification"] forKey:@"Classification"];
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForClassification copy]];
        }
        else
        {
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"createdDate"] forKey:@"createdDate"];
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[[feeds objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Classification"] forKey:@"Classification"];
            [dictionForClassification setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count]  forKey:@"noOfOccurence"];
            [arrFinalValues addObject:[dictionForClassification copy]];
        }
    }
```

Change the If statement to While loop can already